# What to expect from a H81 motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard, chipset

I'm building a budget gaming PC with an Asrock H81 motherboard. I'm about to buy my RAM, but I just saw on the description that H81 is not in the list of the "supported" chipsets. The motherboard is an Asrock H81M and the RAM a Kingston Technology KHX16C9B1BK2/8.
I read this article http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Z87-H87-H81-Q87-Q85-B85-What-is-the-difference-473/ but it appears to be wrong because it says the CrossFire is not supported by H81 motherboard, but it is on this one. It also says that this kind of "incompatibility" may result in missing features.

So I'd like to know what I should expect when buying these two components.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you read the ram wasn't compatible?

Comment: @Paul I saw in the description on Amazon.fr : http://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B00AHWXTZ4/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A1X6FK5RDHNB96

It's said : Compatible: Avec Intel P55, H67, P67, Z68, Z77 et H61 et les chipsets AMD A75, A87, A88, A89, A78, E35

Comment: RAM can be tricky.  If it isn't listed as compatible, it might work and it might not.  The best approach is to choose from the compatibility list: http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H81M/?cat=Memory

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. The problem is solved now.